# Terminal to boot from USB?

Tags: boot

In my last [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649122/cant-get-off-lock-screen) I stated I can't get off of the lock screen. Is there a terminal command to boot up from a usb port? I have windows 7 on that and I think that could change my checkmate.

Comment: Your computer can't easily control how you boot (if at all) that has to be managed through the BIOS. The BIOS and the operating system are completely independent so if you are having BIOS issues they are most likely unrelated to your lock screen issue (which should actually be easy to fix).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to change your boot sequence in BIOS or UEFI to boot from a bootable USB drive on hardware capable of doing that. How you get to the BIOS/UEFI interface to change the boot sequence depends on the hardware you're using.

Comment: BIOS is unreachable. Problem with program....